# How to insert data into two table which has PK , FK relation in MS-Access using JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

I have two table Order1 (OrderNO is PK in Order1)and order2 (OrderNO is FK in order2 ) in MS Access , i have to insert data in this two table using JDBC. so please can any one tell me the sol. i try it but data is inserting in only 1 st table and gives error INSERT INTO is wrong

Comment: Please post your code in which you're getting error

Comment: I bet it's not a jdbc or MS-Access problem but a sql problem - you should add that tag also... please post your outgoing sql statement also... Btw, you can test your sql statement in MS-Access directly to be sure it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use batch update facility of JDBC 2.0 in order to insert into multiple tables as a batch or as a single unit. In this case your application will hit underlying database(MS access in your case) only once so performance will be increased as compared to one by one insertion.

You can add below given code in your own..
or simply can get idea that how to implement.

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
con.setAutoCommit(false);

stmt.addBatch("INSERT INTO Order1 VALUES (OrderNO , ..., ...)");
stmt.addBatch("INSERT INTO Order2 VALUES (OrderNO , ...)");

int [] updateCounts = stmt.executeBatch();
```

Here AutoCommit() is set to false so it will free your application to decide whether to commit or not if any one of command in batch fails to execute or in case of any other error.